# Pick UIImage using UImageNamed and add them on NSArray

Tags: ios, uiimage, nsarray

I've created a custom uiimage picker.

I have multiples UIImage with this name : "Soiree-blabla.png" added manually to my xCode project

What i want is to get all these images and add them on an NSarray and then show them on my custom image picker.

How do i do that ?

I was wondering if i could create a Json WS on my website which could return an Array of String containing the names of all my images and save them to userdefaults (because all these images will be on a ftp on my sites too!)

And then i could create my Array with this :

```
NSArray *images = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"EventImages"];
for (NSString *imageName on images)
{
     UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
     [self.arrayOfEventImages addObject:image];
}
```

But i don't know if this is really "relevant" :(

Thanks!

Comment: What do you really want ? To load your images stored local in your app ? To download them from your server ?

Comment: @danypata Load the images stored local :) But i want to load them really quickly not by entering the name of ALL the images..

Comment: can you post the "blabla" format ? It's really important to know if it can be generated:D

Comment: @danypata Yes! For exemple : Soiree-Home.png, Soiree-Love.png, Soiree-Locked.png etc. I have approximately 50 or 60 images :(

Comment: @danypata is it possible to use an NSRegularExpression like : @"/^Soiree-*.png$/ or something like that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

Copy all your images into a directory into your project, let's call it "Images"

Then use the following code snippet:

```
NSString * resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
NSString * documentsPath = [resourcePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Images"];
NSError * error;
NSArray * folderContent= [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsPath error:&error];
```

And in the folder content you will have all the image names.

Comment: There's something wrong... ![Check](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s199/sh/0f875476-aad7-48ab-b551-04e37a5dc129/e676900ee24d930131c0daccd1fe9ade)

Comment: Can you be more specific ?

Comment: Check what the `error` says. And make sure you have folders there, not only groups

Comment: 2013-05-17 23:54:32.418 iVent[15950:907] ERROR Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)" UserInfo=0x1f3a7970 {NSUnderlyingError=0x1f29e220 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory", NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Applications/6ABC82F0-4399-4EB5-8EC7-1F7F2404E259/iVent.app/Ressources/Images/EventImagesCategory, NSUserStringVariant=(
    Folder
)}

Comment: When you created the groups for the images did you also create folders for the groups ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30158/discussion-between-danypata-and-pwyll28)

Comment: I have created the folders already : ! [Screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s199/sh/792c9edf-2cb4-451b-b6b0-b62d68d8960b/9bb1ec6e22fb87ad0b9ba4d0dd026bb1)